# STRING_AGG Not Recognized on V15.0.2 of SQL Server LocalDB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, sql-server-localdb

I recently coded a stored procedure on SQL Server 2019 (14.0.3192.2) in AWS that utilized the function `STRING_AGG` with no issues. When I moved the code to my local test db it complained about that method.

Upon [research](https://medium.com/cloudnimble/upgrade-visual-studio-2019s-localdb-to-sql-2019-da9da71c8ed6) I proceeded to update my local sql server db service from 14.x version to the latest 15.0.2 and tried to install the sproc again; to the failure

> Incorrect syntax near '"'',STRING_AGG(ActionDATE, ''","''),''"'.

This feature has been viable since SQL Server 2017...so being missing in the local version of 2019 is somewhat puzzling.

### Question

What recourse do I have besides installing SQL Server 2019 Developer edition to resolve this issue?

---

### Intention

Note that the failure line with `STRING_AGG` is trying to create a JSON sub array of dates such as

`[ '01/24/2020', '01/28/2020' ]`:

### Code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [hcwfba].[GetOperationsAndActionDates] 
    @operationId int,
    @locationId int  
AS       

WITH  [DATA] AS (SELECT DISTINCT id_Operation, id_Location , CONVERT(varchar, ActionDATE ,101) AS [ActionDATE] FROM OperationDetail)

SELECT distinct 
         PD.id_Operation
       , PD.id_Location
       , JSON_QUERY((SELECT CONCAT(''["'',STRING_AGG(ActionDATE, ''","''),''"]'') FROM [DATA] DT2 WHERE DT2.id_Location = PD.id_Location)) As Dates
FROM [DATA] PD
WHERE PD.id_Operation = @operationId 
AND PD.id_Location = @locationId
FOR JSON AUTO;

RETURN @@ROWCOUNT
```

### JSON Result

```
[
    {
        "id_Operation": 13,
        "id_Location": 8675309,
        "Dates": [
            "12/03/2018",
            "08/27/2018",
            "10/22/2018"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the `STRING_AGG()` function with a very simple test case to confirm it's an issue with the function and not your syntax in your main query? Are you positive of your SQL Server version in your local instance?

Comment: @J.D. That is it....turns out a tool I was using to move tsql between server/databases was not handling the escapes right. Put up an answer and I will mark it as such.

Comment: Valid line should have been `SELECT CONCAT('["',STRING_AGG(ActionDATE, '","'),'"]') FROM [DATA]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comments: Have you tried to use the `STRING_AGG()` function with a very simple test case to confirm it's an issue with the function and not your syntax in your main query?

It seems your syntax was not formatted properly, rather than the `STRING_AGG()` function not being available on your instance version.